# Getting back at developing... jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, file, browser, locale

It's very simple...

```
<script src="https://xForigens.com/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    Some code
});

</script>
```

Now... when loading the html on my own webpage and it isn't sourced from microsoft and only one js file specifically, jQuery doesn't work when viewing from files nor from webpage. When the jquery.js file, however, is loading from a different server, but the source stays the same, the jquery works and it's stupid.

Long story short.. jquery doesn't work and I am freaking tf out xd

Comment: Use this reference for JQuery instead? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Didn't help my issue, same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. A simple application with reference to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js` using `$(document).ready` will work fine. What exactly is your issue again? Referencing some external JS file? If so, maybe post how you're referencing this file

Comment: Or is it literally just the reference to the JQuery file.. because maybe you're using an old version of JQuery in the JQuery file & are referencing a new version in the script tag.. It _matters_ which version of JQuery you're using depending on your application

Comment: I am referencing as the code shows. Eveything is up to date. The only jQuery file that ist still working is an old out of date one https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: So, the local file. Which version of JQuery is it? 3.1.1?

Comment: And no, the Js-file I am trying to use is not external when seen from the webpage point of view.

Comment: The version I am trying to use now is 3.4.1.

Comment: No, which version is the _local file_ ?

Comment: I don't know how to impact this in any way xd

Comment: Therefore I don't know

Comment: I just can't get jquery to work... no matter if working offline or on an uploaded html

Comment: With the one I am hosting myself of course

Comment: Okay. So you need to find that out. The reason here - and it's an issue I've had multiple times - is that the version of JQuery _matters_. If your application is referencing a library which is before JQuery 3.0, you may have a reliance on deprecated functionality. This means... the functions **will not work** and your program will not run. Therefore. Here is a list of every function that probably won't work in your application if you reference a **newer** version of JQuery: [Migrate up to JQuery 3.0 - 3.4.1](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/)

Comment: Therefore, you have two choices. Update your program to use the newer functionality outlined in the link above. **OR** keep referencing the old JQuery

Comment: `The only jQuery file that ist still working is an old out of date one ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js` i.e. this

Comment: I don't know what to update. As far as I am aware you just had to give a source... What I am trying to say is.. it is not my server, besides managing what files are on there... I don't know and can't change the configuration....

Comment: Yeah, you can give it  a source.. if it's a new one, hit F12 to view all the console errors, those will be things you need to fix. Otherwise, just use the old source `ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js` and hopefully fix nothing

Comment: there are no errors

Comment: What code are you trying to run? Can you post it?

Comment: Posted in answer

Answer (score 0):

trying to run this code

```
<script src="https://xForigens.com/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ASREA").click(function(){
      $(".Popup").css("display","none");
      $(".PopupWindow").css("display","none");
    });
});

function iFrameFriends() {
    var iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrame')[0];
    var input = document.getElementById('LinkBar').innerHTML;
    iFrame.outerHTML = '<iframe id="iFrame" src="https://skribbl.io' + input + '"></iframe>';
};
</script>
```

Comment: My dumb solution I just found are the scriptags. My Tags in Head and Body looked like this <script src=""/>, closing the tag like this isn't helpful in this case and only causes errors. Tried <script src=""></script> and now it gives me what I was looking for